# Split string loaded from SecretsManager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a ListenerRule that would accept only certain IP addresses loaded from Secrets Manager. Here's my original code:

```
LoadBalancerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
        Actions:
            -   TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'TargetGroup'
                Type: 'forward'
        Conditions:
            Fn::If:
                - IsProdEnvironment
                -   -   Field: host-header
                        Values:
                            - !Ref 'BaseUrl'
                -   -   Field: host-header
                        Values:
                            - !Ref 'BaseUrl'
                    -   Field: source-ip
                        SourceIpConfig:
                            Values:
                                - !Split [ ';', !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:/${ProjectName}/${EnvType}/${ServiceName}:SecretString:ALLOWED_IPS}}' ]
```

Resolve above seems to work properly and is resolved to a string like `1.2.3.4/32;2.3.4.5/32;4.5.6.7/29;5.6.7.8/32` (addresses obviously obfuscated but the amount and subnet mask is the same).

However when I try to deploy the template I get an error:

`The specified value '1.2.3.4/32;2.3.4.5/32;4.5.6.7/29;5.6.7.8/32' is not a valid CIDR block (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: error-id)`

This error by itself suggests that `!Split` does something because CloudFormation does not report error `Value of property Values must be of type List of String`. Clearly string was converted to a list containing one element but it was not split by `;` character into list of 4 strings.

Also, when I try to run very similar code but with hardcoded value instead of secret it works fine:

```
LoadBalancerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
        Actions:
            -   TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'TargetGroup'
                Type: 'forward'
        Conditions:
            Fn::If:
                - IsProdEnvironment
                -   -   Field: host-header
                        Values:
                            - !Ref 'BaseUrl'
                -   -   Field: host-header
                        Values:
                            - !Ref 'BaseUrl'
                    -   Field: source-ip
                        SourceIpConfig:
                            Values:
                                !Split [';', '1.2.3.4/32;2.3.4.5/32;4.5.6.7/29;5.6.7.8/32' ]
```

I also checked version without `!Sub` but with hardcoded path to Secret value:

```
LoadBalancerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
        Actions:
            -   TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'TargetGroup'
                Type: 'forward'
        Conditions:
            Fn::If:
                - IsProdEnvironment
                -   -   Field: host-header
                        Values:
                            - !Ref 'BaseUrl'
                -   -   Field: host-header
                        Values:
                            - !Ref 'BaseUrl'
                    -   Field: source-ip
                        SourceIpConfig:
                            Values: !Split [';', '{{resolve:secretsmanager:/dummy-project/dev/foo:SecretString:ALLOWED_IPS}}']
```

As a result I get the same error as in first case: long string is not split into smaller parts.

To make this even weirder... this is a part of quite large template but when I copy this resource to a simple `test.yaml` that takes a list of Parameters required to generate SecretManager path it seems to be working properly...

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: I would go on a limb and say that probably `resolve` happens after `!Split` has happened, so `!Split` treats that whole string like a literal. At least docs mention that `resolve` happens when changeset is applied: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html.I would dig in this direction.

Comment: I see only `!Sub` in the first template. Where is the `!Split` which you talk about? In the two other templates I see the `!Split`, but not in the first one.

Comment: @Marcin Sorry, I pasted wrong snippet from my attempts - I used version without `Split` at some point to verify that Secret is resolved and that without Split error message is actually different. I edited the post to fix the first snippet (question remains the same)

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide full answer as I agree @OleksiiDonoha and I belive that `resolve:secretsmanager` is resolves last, during change set creation, after all intrinsic functions are executed.

However, I would like to clarify the statement:

> This error by itself suggests that !Split does something because CloudFormation does not report error Value of property Values must be of type List of String.

`!Split` uses only `String`, not list of strings, unlike `Select`. Also, if you provide wrong delimiter it will just return the original string.

So what is happening with `Split`, I think, is the following:

In the expression:

```
  Values:
    - !Split [ ';', !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:/${ProjectName}/${EnvType}/${ServiceName}:SecretString:ALLOWED_IPS}}' ]
```

`!Sub` executes first and you end up with (for example):

```
  Values:
    - !Split [ ';', '{{resolve:secretsmanager:/MyProject/TestType/MyService:SecretString:ALLOWED_IPS}}' ]
```

Then `!Split` executes and attempts to split the string `'{{resolve:secretsmanager:/MyProject/TestType/MyService:SecretString:ALLOWED_IPS}}'` by `;`. It can't, thus you end up with:

```
  Values:
    - '{{resolve:secretsmanager:/MyProject/TestType/MyService:SecretString:ALLOWED_IPS}}'
```

And finally now this gets resolved, resulting in:

```
  Values:
    - "1.2.3.4/32;2.3.4.5/32;4.5.6.7/29;5.6.7.8/32"
```

This would explain your error.

The only solution I see at present would to use custom resource which would get the secret before the intrinsic functions evaluate or through an inner stack.

Alternatively, you are chaining stacks (one stacks produces outputs which go into parameters of the next stack) you could resolve the secret in the first stack, and just pass the CIDRs string list as a parameter to the second stack.

Hope this helps.